# Auto delete new mail from cPanel

Tags: email, cpanel

To save the disk quota, I forwarded all new incoming emails to gmail, unfortunately the mail server keep a copy in inbox. How can I delete all incoming emails after forward while I have the cPanel to manage the server.

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/forwarded-mail-stays-server-how-delete-50935.html) or [this link](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/how-auto-delete-all-emails-older-than-2-years-cpanel-any-scripts-121345.html#post529045) on how to delete mail automatically.

If you want to do it manually, one way is to do it from within cPanel. Go to the *File Manager*, you will see a directory called *Mail* (on the righthand column).

Comment: Another related link [here](http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/auto-delete-email-when-forwarded-46657.html)

Comment: Please also check [**How do I auto delete old emails on CPanel ?**](http://www.sellwebhost.com/knowledgebase/28/How-do-I-auto-delete-old-emails-on-CPanel--.html)

Comment: You can also try [**Setting up your cPanel email address in Gmail**](http://yooweb.me/blog/deggertsen/setting-your-cpanel-email-address-gmail) or [**Google Mail Fetcher setup for cPanel email account**](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9189/2186/google-mail-fetcher-setup-for-cpanel-email-account)